# Setting a JProgressBar

Tags: java, swing, runnable, event-dispatch-thread, jprogressbar

I'm using `javax.swing` to build the GUI for a little application. Everything is working fine, but I just a have a little doubt. I would like to use a `JProgressBar` to indicate that the process export is running. 
As the class Post itself implements `Runnable`, if call `setIndeterminate()` just after `run()`, it's executed even before `export()` is over, as Java put it in another `Thread`.

Does anyone have some idea how to solve it?

```
    this.jProgressBar2.setIndeterminate(true);
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            Post post = new Post();
            post.export();
        }
    });

    this.jProgressBar2.setIndeterminate(true);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that since `post.export()` is being run in a background thread (I assume) then your code does not block, and the code after the run method will be called immediately.

Suggestions:

- Get rid of the `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {` statement as the code is already running on the Swing event thread and so this does nothing.
- You need some notification mechanism for when post is done exporting. Give Post a SwingPropertyChangeSupport object, as well as an `addPropertyChangeListener(...)` method that allows outside classes (here the GUI) to add PropertyChangeListeners and use this with beans binding as well as PropertyChangeListeners to notify the GUI when the processing is done. This is done by calling the appropriate `firePropertyChange(...)` on the support object when the export is done.